# How can I install nodemon on windows 10?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, nodemon

I am using the bash console in windows 10. I am using node.js and I want to install nodemon, but I get this:

```
sudo: npm: command not found
```

and I'm supposed to have npm

Comment: You need to install npm. What is the question?

Comment: `find / -name npm` ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't finish writing the post. The problem I have is that I already install npm, but when installing nodemon it tells me that I don't have it installed. But when I put on the ```npm -v```  console, I get the version. So if it is installed. The question is is there another way to install no demon without npm? Or is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: I fixed it, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Providing information about how you installed npm could be useful. Assuming you used windows and not bash to install npm, that is probably why you might be having an issue.

Try installing node through bash console.

Install git first

```
apt-get install git
```

Get the latest version of node

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
```

Install node

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

if it still doesn't work **SOMETIMES** node will get installed as nodeJS so you might have to create a hard link

```
ln -s `which nodejs` /usr/bin/node
```